# Debian apt cannot find cairo-dock package, only on laptop

Tags: linux, debian, apt, cairo-dock

Recently migrated my desktop and laptop back to Debian. I'm running `stretch, 4.6.0-1-amd64`. Both my desktop and laptop have the same `sources.list`, but only the desktop is able to find and install `cairo-dock` via `apt`. This is a little confusing, because I'm struggling to find any difference between the apt setup of both that would lead to this behavior.

**sources.list**

```
deb http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

# backports
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cairo-dock is not part of stretch or jessie-backports.
https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/cairo-dock

Comment: oh, that's weird, why does my desktop with the same setup have no trouble finding it?

Comment: It has trouble also. Try `apt-get install --reinstall cairo-dock`

Comment: @borysn it was removed from Stretch in mid-July; could you have installed it before then?

Comment: I gotcha. I think I know what happened then. I installed debian 8 on the desktop, set it up with cairo-dock, then did an upgrade for 9. Then on the laptop I just used an iso for 9, rather than doing an upgrade 8->9.